# Convert string into XML structure XSLT

Tags: xslt

I am getting an input structure as something like this

```
 &lt;ParameterSet&gt;2|InterfaceMethod|EQ|I|GenericQuery|NIL&lt;/ParameterSet&gt;
 &lt;ParameterSet&gt;1|TargetFilename|EQ|I|VendorMaster|NIL&lt;/ParameterSet&gt;
```

the output should look something like below

```
  <Parameter>
    <Expression>2</Expression>
    <Parametername>InterfaceMethod</Parametername>
    <Parameter_Opt>EQ</Parameter_Opt>
    <Parameter_Sign>I</Parameter_Sign>
    <Range_Low_Value>GenericQuery</Range_Low_Value>
    <Range_High_Value>NIL</Range_High_Value>
  </Parameter>
  <Parameter>
    <Expression>1</Expression>
    <Parametername>TargetFilename</Parametername>
    <Parameter_Opt>EQ</Parameter_Opt>
    <Parameter_Sign>I</Parameter_Sign>
    <Range_Low_Value>VendorMaster</Range_Low_Value>
    <Range_High_Value>NIL</Range_High_Value>
  </Parameter>
```

My Problem is the tag  gets converted to <ParameterSet&gt and am not able to use foreach when I write into another repetitive structure.

Can anyone provide some sample code.

Answer (score 3):

The operation you are looking for - turning lexical XML into a tree of nodes - is called parsing. Some XSLT processors have an extension function, e.g. saxon:parse(), that does this (in XSLT 3.0 it's available out-of-the-box as fn:parse-xml()). With other processors, you may be able to write your own extension function by calling out to Java or Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Your input data isn't XML, possibly it's encoded (escaped) XML. So, you need to turn it into well-formed XML, in other words perform pre-processing. Then apply XSL transform.

Comment: Yes, and I think the question was, "Can I do this preprocessing also in XSLT?"  The answer seems to be "Yes" for XSLT 3.0, and "Perhaps, using a processor-specific extension" for earlier versions.

Answer (score 0):

xslt is good at rearranging xml into different xml, not at changing non-xml into xml.  While you *could* do this with xslt using lots of nested `substring-before` or the like, it will be much much easier if you can run it through `sed` or something first to create xml out of the |-delimited string.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your inputs, I wanted this solution in XSLT as that is only processor I had and also it is running on version 1.0. Got it working with the code below

```
        <xsl:variable name="TempArea">
&lt;ParameterSet&gt;2|InterfaceMethod|EQ|I|GenericQuery|NIL&lt;/ParameterSet&gt;
&lt;ParameterSet&gt;1|TargetFilename|EQ|I|VendorMaster|NIL&lt;/ParameterSet&gt;
&lt;ParameterSet&gt;1|CompanyCode|EQ|I|4900|NIL&lt;/ParameterSet&gt;</xsl:when>
        </xsl:variable>


            <xsl:call-template name="for.loop.Parameters">
                <xsl:with-param name="sourceNodes" select="substring-after($TempArea,'&lt;ParameterSet&gt;')"/>
            </xsl:call-template>

    <xsl:template name="for.loop.Parameters">
        <xsl:param name="sourceNodes"/>
        <xsl:variable name="temp">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="string-length($sourceNodes) &gt; '0'">
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($sourceNodes,'&lt;/ParameterSet&gt;')"/>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:variable name="Expression" select="substring-before($temp, '|')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="remaining" select="substring-after($temp, '|')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="Name" select="substring-before($remaining, '|')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="remainingNext" select="substring-after($remaining, '|')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="Option" select="substring-before($remainingNext, '|')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="remainingNext1" select="substring-after($remainingNext, '|')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="Sign" select="substring-before($remainingNext1, '|')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="remainingNext2" select="substring-after($remainingNext1, '|')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="LowValue" select="substring-before($remainingNext2, '|')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="HighValue" select="substring-after($remainingNext2, '|')"/>

        <Parameter>
            <Expression>
                <xsl:value-of select="$Expression"/>
            </Expression>
            <Parametername>
                <xsl:value-of select="$Name"/>
            </Parametername>
            <Parameter_Opt>
                <xsl:value-of select="$Option"/>
            </Parameter_Opt>
            <Parameter_Sign>
                <xsl:value-of select="$Sign"/>
            </Parameter_Sign>
            <Range_Low_Value>
                <xsl:value-of select="$LowValue"/>
            </Range_Low_Value>
            <Range_High_Value>
                <xsl:value-of select="$HighValue"/>
            </Range_High_Value>
        </Parameter>

        <xsl:variable name="test">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($sourceNodes,'&lt;/ParameterSet&gt;')"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:if test="string-length($test)&gt; 1 ">
            <xsl:call-template name="for.loop.Parameters">
                <xsl:with-param name="sourceNodes">
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($test,'&lt;ParameterSet&gt;')"/>
                </xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
```